# Center 3 images evenly on page

Tags: html, css

I have a main page of my site

And I have been trying to get the images to be even spaced and centered on the page but have been failing.

```css
{
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a
{
  color: #06f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.button
{
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #06f;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover
{
  background-color: #06f;
  color: #fff;
}

.headline
{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content
{
  max-width: 650px;
}

.grid-wrapper
{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 125px;
}

.grid-item
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.grid-content
{
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-image-link
{
  display: block;
  height: 290px;
}

.grid-image
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
}

#albumView{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#indexMain{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul class="grid-wrapper">
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="triangulation/triangulation.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290"/>
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/triangulation">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="distort-grid/distort-grid.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" alt="manipulated image of president lincoln" />
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/distort-grid">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="contrastdistort/contrastdistort.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" />
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/contrast-distort">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I have attempted to use % to get it just right, but it never seems to adjust correctly.

I am stumped and could use some help, is there anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Hi centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Horizontally, that what I am looking for

Comment: You might want to look into 'margin:auto'

Comment: You should set max-width to image container (ul, in this case, and 750px, in this case), and use margin: auto.... other options are: using of flex, or display:table...https://jsfiddle.net/xndkgbqk/

Comment: If it was of any help...consider accepting one of the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use display:flex and to evenly space it justify-content:space-between and to center it use margin:auto

check this snippet

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="grid-wrapper">
      <li class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-content">
          <a class="grid-image-link" href="triangulation/triangulation.html">
            <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" />
          </a>
          <p>
            repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/triangulation">github</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-content">
          <a class="grid-image-link" href="distort-grid/distort-grid.html">
            <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" alt="manipulated image of president lincoln" />
          </a>
          <p>
            repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/distort-grid">github</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-content">
          <a class="grid-image-link" href="contrastdistort/contrastdistort.html">
            <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" />
          </a>
          <p>
            repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/contrast-distort">github</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Remove `float:left` from both `ul` and `li` and add `padding:0;` in `ul`

```css
body
{
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a
{
  color: #06f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.button
{
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #06f;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover
{
  background-color: #06f;
  color: #fff;
}

.headline
{
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content
{
  max-width: 650px;
}

.grid-wrapper
{/*
  float: left;*/
  padding:0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 125px;
}

.grid-item
{
  display: block;/*
  float: left;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.grid-content
{
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-image-link
{
  display: block;
  height: 290px;
}

.grid-image
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
}

#albumView{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#indexMain{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul class="grid-wrapper">
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="triangulation/triangulation.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290"/>
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/triangulation">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="distort-grid/distort-grid.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" alt="manipulated image of president lincoln" />
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/distort-grid">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="grid-item">
          <div class="grid-content">
            <a class="grid-image-link" href="contrastdistort/contrastdistort.html">
              <img class="grid-image" src="http://placehold.it/290x290" />
            </a>
            <p>
              repository on <a href="https://github.com/snorpey/contrast-distort">github</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: OP wants to center horizontally